# App Engine order of POSTs vs order of inserts

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

First off, I'm pretty new to GAE and the datastore so I'm not used to the big-scaling, eventual consistency etc stuff yet :)

But, I'm designing a backend for a small multiplayer game. Players/clients post events as something is happening, and other clients poll to get those events. Events are stored with ndb.DateTimeProperty fields with auto_now_add=True (creation_time).

However, last night I noticed something weird, it seems like the order of them get mixed up sometimes. Even though "POST event 1" was done like one second before "POST event 2", event 2 could get saved a few milliseconds before event 1 (either that, or my client code is bad :)). This was when using the dev_appserver by the way, haven't tried it in real GAE yet.

I guess my (first) question is; is this normal GAE behaviour? Maybe there are no guarantees that one request is processed (saved) before another, regardless when the requests come in?

And if so, is there some way of getting this behaving as I would like? Keeping the order of the entities somehow? The events have the same ancestor (the game), and are stored in transactions.. At least I hope so, I've tagged methods with @ndb.transactional :-)

If I set the datetime manually on the events, with datetime.now() instead of auto_now_add, in the POST handler before saving the entity, would that work? Are different GAE instances time-synchronized?

Hmm.. The more I think about it, the more impossible it feels :) ..Should the clients set the timestamps of the events themselves?? They could have the wrong time set of course, but maybe they could sync time with the server first or something.. ?

Comment: dev server emulates the datastore. Try it on the real thing before drawing any conclusions.

Comment: Use auto_now_add, this is the timestamp when the put is run. There can be differences in time between different instances.  In addition if you don't use the key to retrieve the entities it is quite possible that you might see items retrieved/or not.  Fetch the new entities by key and see if the timestamps make sense. As the other person said, test this in production though, because the dev server can't replicate all of the production operational semantics.

Comment: For good StackOverflow semantics, please convert the "Solved" note into an answer and flag it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solved" by waiting for one request to finish before sending the next one.. :-P